# Adding custom columns with the value of the last user who modified the page to the WordPress admin panel, Pages management

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

[image]

I want to have two custom columns in Pages' table view in WordPress. I could do it for the "Last modified" by built-in functions and below codes:

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns','add_custom_page_columns');
function add_custom_page_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last modified';
    $columns['modified_author'] = 'Modified by';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column','custom_columns_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_columns_content ( $column_id, $post_id ) {
    switch( $column_id ) { 
        case 'last_modified':
            echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
        break;
        
        case 'modified_author':
            echo get_post_meta($post_id, "meta_value", false);
        break;
   }
}
```

The "Last modified" works well, however, I couldn't show who was the last modifier.

I've found in the "wp_postmeta" table > "meta_key" column > _edit_last >

there are

"post_id" shows the page id

"meta_value" shows the last modifier user's id

**For making the "Last modified" column sortable.**

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-page_sortable_columns', 'sortable_page_columns' );
function sortable_page_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last modified';
    return $columns;
}
```

*To use these codes add all of them into the function.php*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.

```php
add_filter('manage_pages_columns','bks_add_custom_page_columns');
function bks_add_custom_page_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['last_modified'] = 'Last modified';
    $columns['modified_author'] = 'Modified by';
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column','bks_custom_columns_content', 10, 2 );
function bks_custom_columns_content ( $column_id, $post_id ) {
    switch( $column_id ) {
        case 'last_modified':
            echo get_post_field('post_modified', $post_id);
            break;

        case 'modified_author':
            echo the_modified_author(); // Changed.
            break;
    }
}
```

I have used `the_modified_author()` function.

> [the_modified_author()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_modified_author/)
> Display the name of the author who last edited the current post, if the author’s ID is available.

Comment: Exactly the "the_modified_author()" was my answer. thanks

Comment: @alifallahi, Great, consider marking this as the correct answer. Thanks!!